# What is wrong with this python program? It hangs after asking for the first characters name

Tags: python, function

Ok, so when the program asks for the first characters name and it gets typed in, it just hangs and nothing happens. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out! Here is my code :

```
import math, random
name1 = ""
name2 = ""
strength1 = 0
strength2 = 0
skill1 = 0
skill2 = 0

def Character1(strength1, skill1, name1):
    name1 = raw_input("Please enter a name for the first character : ")
    strength1 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10
    skill1 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10

def Character2(strength2, skill2, name2):
    name2 = raw_input("Please enter a name for the second character : ")
    strength2 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10
    skill2 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10

def printStats(strength1, skill1, name1, strength2, skill2, name2):
    print "The first character is called " + name1 + " and has a skill level of " + str(skill1) + " and a strength level of " + str(strength1) 
    print "The first character is called " + name2 + " and has a skill level of " + str(skill2) + " and a strength level of " + str(strengths2) 

Character1(strength1, skill1, name1)
Character2(strength2, skill2, name2)
printStats(strength1, skill1, name1, strength2, skill2, name2)
```

P.s : I am using python 2.7

Comment: What do you mean by 'hangs'? Doesn't respond after you entered a name and then used the ENTER key?

Comment: Yeah, nothing happens after I press the enter key to store the name in 'name1'

Comment: What happens when you add a `print` statement in the function?

Comment: Note that Python doesn't pass variables by reference; setting `name1` inside a function only rebinds a function local. The global `name1` doesn't change at all here.

Comment: The `CharacterX` functions won't change the global variable values - `printStats` will print empty names with 0 stat values.

Comment: Not the point but, second line of printStats should also be changed, you mistyped strength2 by strengths2

Comment: Also you have an error on the last print str(strengths2) in printStats. Should be strength2.

Comment: How are you running this? It shouldn't hang, it should print "The first character is called  and has a skill level of 0 and a strength level of 0" then an error message with a traceback and then exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if you have run your code.

First, correct the typos in your code like strengths2, skills1...

Second, if you do want to use global variables, declare them inside function, otherwise the assignment to the global variables will make them local. Below is the code:

```
import math, random
name1 = ""
name2 = ""
strength1 = 0
strength2 = 0
skill1 = 0
skill2 = 0

def Character1():
    global strength1, skill1, name1
    name1 = raw_input("Please enter a name for the first character : ")
    strength1 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10
    skill1 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10

def Character2():
    global strength2, skill2, name2
    name2 = raw_input("Please enter a name for the second character : ")
    strength2 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10
    skill2 = math.floor(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10

def printStats():
    print "The first character is called " + name1 + " and has a skill level of " + str(skill1) + " and a strength level of " + str(strength1) 
    print "The first character is called " + name2 + " and has a skill level of " + str(skill2) + " and a strength level of " + str(strength2) 

Character1()
Character2()
printStats()
```

Comment: Thank you! this code works as I need it to, sorry for being so 'noobish' haha